# Are case-control studies one example of an extreme group design?

Tags: experiment-design, case-control-study

I need to present some research to a field that commonly uses case-control studies (comparing those with a disease versus those without) and it just occured to me that an extreme group design (which I am using) might be very similar. By extreme group design I mean a large number of individuals are measured on X (in my case, 1000) and then a portion are seleceted into high and low groups (such as top and bottom 25% on X). Only the extreme groups are measure on Y. T-tests b/t groups or an estimated correlation for the full sample ([Alf & Abrams, 1975](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02291557?LI=true)) are then obtained. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? (e.g., similarities, differences, pitfalls, dangers)